# If Warwrick sniffs teemo/twitch/evelynn and they stealth, will they still be spotted?

Tags: league-of-legends

My question is: If those champs are sniffed out by Warwick (having less then half health) and then go invisible, will they still be under his effect?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not reveal the enemy, but Warwick will still get the movement speed as if it did.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warwick_the_Blood_Hunter/Ability_Details